# Necesito un buscador PHP para archivos PDF

Tags: php, pdf, buscador

La idea es que a través de un simple formulario buscador, pueda devolver el resultado solicitado buscando en varios PDFs de un directorio, ese buscador tiene que buscar dentro de los pdf que son de texto, generalmente lo  hago todo en PHP, pero si tengo que usar Javascript no hay problema. Hice algo similar con strpos de PHP buscando en unn txt plano, pero si hago eso con PDF no funciona porque es binario.

Bien, ya casi conseguí lo que quiero, solo que ahora el buscador hay algunas palabras que no las encuentra, el código queda así:

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">


<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="buscar">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Buscar">
</form>


<?php




if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {



include_once('class.pdf2text.php');

$directorio = opendir("./pdf"); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{



        $url = 'pdf/'.$archivo;

$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename($url);
$a->decodePDF();
$pdf = utf8_encode($a->output());


$larCharsNoAble = array("Ñ","á","é","í","ó","ú","Á","É","Í","Ó","Ú","ñ","À","Ã","Ì","Ò","Ù","Ã™","Ã ","Ã¨","Ã¬","Ã²","Ã¹","ç","Ç","Ã¢","ê","Ã®","Ã´","Ã»","Ã‚","ÃŠ","ÃŽ","Ã”","Ã›","ü","Ã¶","Ã–","Ã¯","Ã¤","«","Ò","Ã","Ã„","Ã‹");
$larCharsAble = array("N","a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U","n","N","A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u","c","C","a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U","u","o","O","i","a","e","U","I","A","E");
$texto = str_replace($larCharsNoAble, $larCharsAble, $pdf);






$cadena_solicitada   = $_POST['buscar'];
$larCharsNoAble = array("Ñ","á","é","í","ó","ú","Á","É","Í","Ó","Ú","ñ","À","Ã","Ì","Ò","Ù","Ã™","Ã ","Ã¨","Ã¬","Ã²","Ã¹","ç","Ç","Ã¢","ê","Ã®","Ã´","Ã»","Ã‚","ÃŠ","ÃŽ","Ã”","Ã›","ü","Ã¶","Ã–","Ã¯","Ã¤","«","Ò","Ã","Ã„","Ã‹");
$larCharsAble = array("N","a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U","n","N","A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u","c","C","a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U","u","o","O","i","a","e","U","I","A","E");
$post = str_replace($larCharsNoAble, $larCharsAble, $cadena_solicitada);


$posicion_coincidencia = stripos($texto, $post);




if ($posicion_coincidencia == true) {
    echo 'Se ha encontrado "'.$post.'"" en el archivo <a href="'.$url.'">'.$archivo.'</a><br>';
} 


 }

}


?>
```

Comment: El [formato PDF es muy complejo](http://duff-johnson.com/2014/08/21/3-key-tips-for-beating-acrobats-z-order-nightmare/) y tiene tratamientos distintos según el lenguaje que quieras usar para su lectura o edición.

Comment: ¿Probaste algo de lo que te propuse?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, está genial! con lo que estoy luchado ahora es con la lectura múltiple de pdf, o conversión, porque el buscador entiende perfecto y va rápido, el problema es que le tengo que poner manualmente en el código la url, intenté con variable en `$a->setFilename('archivo.pdf');` pero no puedo, todo el código queda mas o menos así:

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$directorio = opendir("./pdf"); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{ echo $archivo . "<br />";
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('archivo.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
$pdf = utf8_encode($a->output());`

Comment: `$cadena_buscada   = $_POST['buscar'];
$posicion_coincidencia = strripos($pdf, $cadena_buscada);
 } if ($posicion_coincidencia === false) {echo "NO se ha encontrado la palabra deseada!!!!";} else {echo "Éxito!!! Se ha encontrado la palabra buscada en la posición: ".$posicion_coincidencia;} ?>`

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la nueva información a la pregunta? Como respuesta no se entiende y se corta. Y si es una pregunta nueva, aunque esté relacionada, marca como respuesta correcta y abre una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @Pablo - ¿Podrías agregar ejemplos de las palabras que no encuentra? ¿Cómo aparecen en `$pdf`? Sería bueno que imprimas el contenido de `$pdf` para ver cómo aparecen.. (además, si los comentarios anteriores ya no aplican, sería bueno que los elimines para que no confundan)

Comment: ¿Podrías confirmar si tu problema se solucionó usando `composer` y la librería que te propuse? Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que necesitas es acceder al contenido de texto de un documento PDF tienes varias formas de hacerlo.

Una de ellas es usando esta clase: http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a

Uso:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('test.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

Y otra opción sería usar una herramienta CLI ([`pdftotext`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) por ejemplo) para ser llamada, por ejemplo, haciendo uso de [`system()`](http://php.net/system) o, mejor aún, el [operador comilla invertida](http://php.net/operators.execution):

```
$texto = `pdftotext -raw document.pdf`;
```

---

Edición: Como he probado la librería que te recomendé y no funciona demasiado bien (`pdftotext` sí lo hace perfectamente), te recomiendo [ésta otra llamada `pdfparser`](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser) que debe instalarse a través de [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/download/) usando, por ejemplo, [`php composer.phar require smalot/pdfparser`](http://www.pdfparser.org/documentation).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Buscador de PDFs</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="Palabras a buscar"
             value="<?= isset($_POST['buscar'])?htmlspecialchars($_POST['buscar']):'' ?>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
  include 'vendor/autoload.php';
  /* Configurar 'es_ES.UTF8' o cualquier local UTF-8 disponible para quitar
    el que viene por defecto, POSIX, que no funciona correctamente. Ojo con la
    local 'C.UTF-8': no convierte signos de puntuación como exclamaciones. */
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'es_ES.UTF-8', 'es.UTF-8', 'C.UTF-8');
  $post = strtolower(iconv(mb_detect_encoding($_POST['buscar'], 'utf-8,iso-8859-15'), 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $_POST['buscar']));
  echo "<p>Buscando la/s palabra/s '", htmlspecialchars($post), "'</p>\n";
  /* Subdirectorio "pdf" dentro de la ruta actual */
  $directorio = opendir(__DIR__ . '/pdf');
  /* Vamos obteniendo los archivos uno a otro */
  while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) {
    /* Si el archivo no tiene extensión '.pdf' pasamos al siguiente */
    if (!preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $archivo)) {
      continue;
    }
    /* Obtenemos el contenido del archivo PDF */
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile(__DIR__ . '/pdf/' . $archivo);
    $texto = $pdf->getText();
    /* Normalizamos el contenido del documento PDF igual que hicimos con la consulta */
    $texto = strtolower(iconv(mb_detect_encoding($texto, 'utf-8,iso-8859-15'), 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $texto));
    echo "<p>Probando en el archivo '", htmlspecialchars($archivo), "': '" . htmlspecialchars($texto) . "'</p>\n";
    $posicion_coincidencia = strpos($texto, $post);
    if ($posicion_coincidencia !== false) {
      echo 'Se ha encontrado "', htmlspecialchars($post), '" en el archivo <a href="pdf/', urlencode($archivo), '">',
        htmlspecialchars($archivo), '</a><br>';
    } 
  }
}
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ten en cuenta que es muy importante para el funcionamiento de la función `//TRANSLIT` de [`iconv`](http://php.net/function.iconv) la correcta configuración de la localización del sistema.

Comment: En parte lo hace, aunque sin dar excesivos detalles. Quiere buscar cadenas dentro de PDFs que tiene en un directorio usando PHP o JavaScript (éste último hace pensar que pudiera querer hacerlo en el lado del cliente, pero en ese caso tendrías razón, necesitaría ampliar detalles) y que ha intentado abrirlo con `file_get_contents()` obteniendo datos binarios, que suele ser lógico si tiene imágenes incrustadas. Lo que podría producirse es que el PDF fueran todas imágenes y deseara hacer OCR sobre él, que sería otra opción más.

Comment: Creo que si @OscarGarcia ha querido molestarse en responder y poner el código es porque cree que lo que han preguntado es su respuesta, no se porque hay que puntuarle negativo.

Comment: @Spidvmp probablemente mi respuesta no sea lo que busca porque no ha aclarado detalles como, por ejemplo, si los PDF están en el servidor o en el equipo del cliente, o si el PDF tiene sólo imágenes y hay que extraerlas para pasarles OCR, etc... probablemente los negativos vengan de no haber contemplado esas posibilidades, pero también es cierto que podría dejar un comentario quien puntúe negativo para, al menos, explicar el motivo. Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: De donde descargo vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Te copio/pego lo que puse en la respuesta: debe instalarse a través de [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/download/) usando, por ejemplo, [`php composer.phar require smalot/pdfparser`](http://www.pdfparser.org/documentation). `Composer` es un sistema de instalación de dependencias que es ampliamente usado en la comunidad PHP (e imprescindible cuando desarrollas usando frameworks).

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia , el problema es que este código va a estar alojado en un webhosting compartido, es necesario instalar algo por ssh? porque si es asi no me va a ser útil

Comment: Puedes instalarlo en tu máquina y luego subir el directorio `vendor` (donde se instalan todas las cosas requeridas por `composer`) al servidor.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Es una respuesta clara no entiendo porque lo **negativo** *(aunque por otra parte lo que menciona **lois6b** tiene razón, bueno hasta yo he preguntado así no justificó entiendo que no se debe)* un +1 la pregunta está muy clara no es justificable el voto negativo saludos :)

Comment: @J.Doe muchas gracias por el apoyo. Respondí (20 ene, 9:29) antes de que la pregunta se cerrara (20 ene, 10:15). Llegué a tener 4 votos negativos. Entendí (o creí entender) lo que preguntaba desde el primer momento porque yo también he tratado de acceder al contenido de PDFs y me he encontrado con los mismos problemas (sobre todo con los diccionarios de palabras que ofuscan el contenido del texto), por lo que le ofrecí la misma solución que usé (el programa pdftotext). Me ha venido bien porque por el camino he descubierto otra herramienta (pdfparser) que no requiere de aplicación externa.

Comment: Supongo que a ciertas personas (a las que no guardo ningún tipo de rencor) no les hace gracia la idea de responder, o que alguien haya respondido, si la pregunta no está formulada como desean. Agradezco el apoyo a los que han votado la reapertura.

Comment: Tal vez yo no sea suficientemente inteligente para **entender los votos negativos** Sólo alcanzo a entender el interés de @OscarGarcia por ayudarnos a desentrañar los pdf y hacer búsquedas eficientes dentro de ellos. Si eso molesta a algún purista: ¡me alegra! Gracias Oscar